# get value of hidden dropdown disabled selected option

Tags: html, jquery, dropdown

I have a simple dropdown list with the first option selected and disabled and two other options
when I click on "Submit" and the dropdown is shown I get the value of the dropdown
When the dropdown list is hidden I always get the value "null" even when I trying to set the value to a string "None" with $("#select").val("None") commmand

How can I set the value to "None" after hiding the dropdown list ?

===== Code output: ====

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn1").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
    $("select").hide();
    $("select").val("None");
  });
  $(".btn2").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
    $("select").show();
    $("#select option:first").prop("selected", true);
  });
  $("#btnSmbt").click(function() {
    $("#select").val("None");
    alert($("#select").val());
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<select id="select">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Number</option>
    <option value"1">1</option>
    <option value"2">2</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<button class="btn1">Hide</button>
<button class="btn2">Show</button>
<br><br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnSmbt" name="btnSmbt">Submit</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your drop down has 3 options, blank, "1", "2" - which one were you trying to select with "None"?

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of issues in your code. Firstly the HTML has some errors in the `option` elements; you're missing the `=` between the `value` attribute and the value you provide.

Secondly, in the jQuery code you're setting the value of `'None'` to the select, yet no option it contains has that value. I presume you're trying to select the first `option` element so that should be an empty string instead: `.val('')`.

Lastly you `alert()` the value *after* you re-set it back to the default. This is why you always see nothing in the alert itself. Swap those lines around.

With that said, try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn1").click(function() {
    $("p").hide();
    $("select").hide();
    $("select").val('');
  });
  
  $(".btn2").click(function() {
    $("p").show();
    $("select").show();
    $("select").val('');
  });
  
  $("#btnSmbt").click(function() {
    alert($("#select").val());
    $("#select").val('');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<select id="select">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select Number</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select><br><br>

<button class="btn1">Hide</button>
<button class="btn2">Show</button><br><br>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnSmbt" name="btnSmbt">Submit</button>
```

Comment: beaten by a minute :)

Answer (score 0):

"None" is not existing value in your select option , thus it'll give you null

Also you html value options misses the `=`

In order to get a value you have to set an existing value between those option by example `1` or `2` as your example shows see below snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn1").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
    $("select").hide();
    $("select").val("1");
  });
  $(".btn2").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
    $("select").show();
    $("#select option:first").prop("selected", true);
  });
  
  $("#btnSmbt").click(function() {
    $("#select").val();
    alert($("#select").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<select id="select">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Number</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<button class="btn1">Hide</button>
<button class="btn2">Show</button>
<br><br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnSmbt" name="btnSmbt">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, note that `disabled` controls do not have values.

So your first option, which is disabled, will always give the value `null` regardless of its actual value

See the snippet for a demonstration of two `select`, one with disabled entry.

```js
console.log($("#select1").val())
console.log($("#select2").val())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
    <option value="anyvalue" disabled selected>Select Number</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
    <option value="anyvalue" selected>Select Number</option>
</select>
```

---

The actual issue in your code is likely (as pointed out in other answers) due to clearing it before displaying it.  But for future reference if anyone tries to get a values of a disabled `option`, this would be the cause of it giving `null`.